# Intepretation of the fact that $\operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, intuition, group-actions

I know how to prove the fact that $\operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$ but I'm having trouble finding meaning behind it. Does someone know why this is useful or has an intuitive view of this matter?

Comment: You can think of it as a change of base point. For example, if $X$ is your Cayley graph then left-multiplication by $g$ moves everything by $g$, so to find the elements which stabilise $g\cdot x$ you head along the path $g^{-1}$, find everything which fixes the point $x$, and then retract your steps back to $g\cdot x$. Indeed, when thinking about fundamental groups, conjugation $\pi_1(S, x)^g$ corresponds *precisely* to change of base point, $\pi_1(S, g\cdot x)$.

Comment: One importance is that if we know the stabilizer of a point $x$, then we suddenly know it for every point in the orbit of $x$, and in particular they are equinumerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an intuition.

Suppose you are standing on the point $g \cdot x$.

Now three things happen quickly in succession:

1. $g^{-1}$ moves you from $g \cdot x$ to $x$;
2. Someone spins the space around $x$ but leaves you fixed in position at $x$ (although perhaps leaving you somewhat dizzy)
3. And then $g$ moves you back from $x$ to $g\cdot x$.

The result: You started standing at $g \cdot x$, and you're still standing at $g \cdot x$.

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Berci